# Setting a flag does not work in my timer Interrupt (while the Interrupt is working)

Tags: timer, interrupt, avr, avr-gcc, atmelstudio

I used to write my codes in ICCAVR and I had no problem there, but not for some reason I should migrate to AtmelStudio.
in the following code, the LED is flashing in the interrupt, but when I only set a flag in the interrupt and want to flash the LED in polling (using the flag) it wouldn't work:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>

#define LED PA1


ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)    // Timer1 ISR
{
    //PORTA ^= (1 << LED);
    TCNT1 = 63974;   // for 1 sec at 16 MHz
    PORTA ^= (1 << LED);
}

int main()
{
    DDRA = (0x01 << LED);     //Configure the PORTD4 as output

    TCNT1 = 63974;   // for 1 sec at 16 MHz

    TCCR1A = 0x00;
    TCCR1B = (1<<CS10) | (1<<CS12);;  // Timer mode with 1024 prescler
    TIMSK = (1 << TOIE1) ;   // Enable timer1 overflow interrupt(TOIE1)
    sei();        // Enable global interrupts by setting global interrupt enable bit in SREG

    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

while this change would make it not to flash:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>

#define LED PA1

unsigned int counter=0;
unsigned char flag=0;

ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)    // Timer1 ISR
{
    //PORTA ^= (1 << LED);
    TCNT1 = 63974;   // for 1 sec at 16 MHz
    counter++;
    if(counter>=10)
    {
        flag=1;
        counter=0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    DDRA = (0x01 << LED);     //Configure the PORTD4 as output

    TCNT1 = 63974;   // for 1 sec at 16 MHz

    TCCR1A = 0x00;
    TCCR1B = (1<<CS10) | (1<<CS12);;  // Timer mode with 1024 prescler
    TIMSK = (1 << TOIE1) ;   // Enable timer1 overflow interrupt(TOIE1)
    sei();        // Enable global interrupts by setting global interrupt enable bit in SREG

    while(1)
    {
        if(flag)
        {
            flag=0;
            PORTA ^= (1 << LED);
        }
    }
}
```

could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler saw that `flag` set to 0 at start of program and can't know that the variable can be changed by interrupt handler (the code never called directly in program).
So it optimized out `flag` check in `while` loop.

Use `volatile` qualifier for variables that accessed from different code streams (main code and interrupt handler, different threads in multi-threaded environment).

```
volatile unsigned char flag = 0;
```